# How to load thumbnails of Pic Clicked via Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, thumbnails, android-external-storage

My application takes pictures via camera intent. How should I display their small size version in a grid view for viewing purpose. Should I create their thumbnails and store them in cache or external storage Or should I use the thumbnails created by Default Gallery application. My pictures are stored in external storage so I am expecting that Default Gallery Application would make their thumbnails automatically. If yes, then how should I map each image with the thumbnail created by Default Gallery Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found that Async class could handle the memory usage scenario.

The relevant link is:  http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have got an answer

```
        public Bitmap getbitpam(String path) {
        Bitmap imgthumBitmap = null;
        try {

            final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE =300 ;

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            imgthumBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

            imgthumBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imgthumBitmap,
                    THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytearroutstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imgthumBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytearroutstream);


        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        return imgthumBitmap;
    }
```

However, this is taking a lot of RAM. I Have also found a strange behavior. That as I am scrolling in grid view, it is taking more RAM. The growth in memory used is cumulative and finally the app is crashing due to Memory_Low exception. Any workaround for it??

Got answer for second problem too:-- Async class.